# Поиск в Magento

Tags: cms, magento, search

Как настроить поиск в CMS Magento так, чтобы при выводе ответа на поиск не выводило ничего лишнего? Просто ввожу например слово "Товар" - не выводит конечно же, а выводит все то, где есть "тов", "вар" или же вообще где нашло букву А или любую из данного слова

Answer (score 0):

В

> System -> Configurations -> Catalog -> Catalog

есть настройки поиска там можно выбрать между **like**, **fulltext** или **combine**(like + fulltext) возможно это поможет, к сожалению стандартный поиск по функционалу и настройкам слабоват и обычно приходится ставить дополнительные модули с использованием **elastic** или **sphinx**.